# Building react-bootstrap on Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, styled-components, react-bootstrap

I'm converting a large CRA app to Gatsby, and there's a deep integration with React-Bootstrap.

All the code works fine while running in development mode, but when building the app I'm getting `WebpackError: ReferenceError: window is not defined`. I have a few third party libraries that have been problematic in the build stage, normally giving them a `null-loader` in `gatsby-node.js` will get past the errors. However some of the React-Bootstrap elements are extended elsewhere in the code by styled-components. Using the null-loader approach then breaks these extensions.

Is there a way to get all this working without rewriting code?

Relevant dependencies from package.json:

```
"bootstrap": "^5.3.0-alpha1",
"react-bootstrap": "^2.7.0",
"react-bootstrap-icons": "^1.10.2",
"gatsby": "^5.11.0",
"gatsby-plugin-styled-components": "^6.11.0",
"styled-components": "^5.3.11",
```